# How to convert enum to string in C# properly?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a `Person` model in my ASP.NET MVC project with a `CityType` property of type `City`. I want to iterate through the database and return the ones matching search criteria.

The problem is I can't convert the `CityType` property to string to check the search property which is a string. I tried something like `CityType.ToString()` but it didn't work.

The error is something like this:

> Id=329, Status = Faulted

But when I remove the piece of code related to `CityType` (`c.CityType.ToString().Contains(search))` in this example), it works fine!

```
public enum City
{
    New York,
    Paris,
    Munich
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public City CityType { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public async Task<List<ContactDTO>> LiveSearchForContacts(string search)
{
    var contacts = await _context.Contacts
                                 .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(search) 
                                          || c.PhoneNumber.Contains(search)
                                          || c.CityType.ToString().Contains(search))
                                 .ToListAsync();

    var contactDTO = new List<ContactDTO>();
    
    foreach (var contact in contacts)
    {
        var dto = _mapper.Map<ContactDTO>(contact);
        contactDTO.Add(dto);
    }

    return contactDTO;
}
```

Comment: That code wouldn't compile in the first place - you can't have spaces in identifiers. (`New York` isn't a valid enum value.)

Comment: Don't convert to string in the first place. Filter using a `City` value instead. If the database field is a text field you can [tell EF to convert the enum to a string automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#pre-defined-conversions)

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. An error that occurs at runtime is called an `Exception` (*this is how errors manifest themselves in .net*). Include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursively across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the  [edit] link on your question to include that detail, *do not* include it as a comment. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Always try to give the most minimal reproducible example with explanation what is happening, and what would you want to happen. In any other way, its hard to help you.

Comment: Side  note: Using an enum for City is a bad idea as this is not naturally expressed or stored as an enumeration. City naturally would be persisted and expressed as a unicode string as it is a name. In the DB make sure you use a unicode type as well (like nvarchar in sql server) and use the correct mapping in EF so there is no conversion to/from ASCII. An Enum is a good choice for a data point where the options are constrained to a small set of known values. An example might be Gender or Day Of the Week.

Comment: The SQL query you're trying to execute is a very bad idea. `WHERE Name LIKE '%seach%' OR City LIKE '%search%' OR ...` can't use any indexes and has to scan the entire table. To speed this up you'd have to use a Full Text Search index in the database itself. To make an FTS search from EF you need to use [EF.Functions.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains?view=efcore-7.0) or `EF.Functions.FreeText` to emit the CONTAINS and FREETEXT operators

Comment: Is City of type INT in the DB Contact table?

Comment: @lidqy Yes it is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `CityType` is stored as a numeric database value, likely an Int32 or equivalent, I'd first do a precheck if there is any City enum value at all whose name can match the search string. Because often there will be none at all.
If there is none, just exclude CityType from the query. If there is one or more, make it an SQL IN(numeric-citytype-values-that-match) expression using Contains in LinQ-To-Entites (assuming also this is an EF query - maybe you should have mentioned your ORM by the way).

```
public async Task<List<ContactDTO>> LiveSearchForContacts(string search)
{
    var cityMatches = Enum.GetValues<City>().Where(c => $"{c:G}".IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgoreCase) > -1);
    var contacts = cityMatches.Any() 
         ? await (_context.Contacts
                                 .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(search) 
                                          || c.PhoneNumber.Contains(search)
                                          || cityMatches.Contains(c.CityType))
                                 .ToListAsync() 
         : await (_context.Contacts
                                 .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(search) 
                                          || c.PhoneNumber.Contains(search)
                                 .ToListAsync();

    var contactDTO = contacts.Select(c => _mapper.Map<ContactDTO>(c)).ToList();

    return contactDTO;
}
```